# How to implement both serve REST (Jersey) request and web page requests using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

I am a very very new REST developer.

What I am trying to do is to serve all `/*.htm` request using controllers and all `/rest/*` requests using Jersey RESTful web services.

I don't know how exactly can I make it work.

REST request works ok, but if I try to request the `index.htm` page, it throws NOT FOUND (404) response.

This is my web.xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ms2.spectrum.security.jersery.JerseyApplication</param-value>          
        </init-param>       
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I have google this question, but I did not found any example where RESTful request and page requests coexists on same Spring MVC application. Maybe I did not use correct search words.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is the `IndexController.java`:

```
package com.ms2.spectrum.security.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView getIndex() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ms2.spectrum.**" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ms2.spectrum.security.controllers.*" />
</beans>
```

**EDIT 3:**

Here is the `JerseyApplication.java` file:

```
package com.ms2.spectrum.security.jersery;

import com.ms2.spectrum.security.jersey.resources.HelloWorld;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter;

/**
 *
 * @author Roger
 */
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication() {
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);
        register(HelloWorld.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you expect to handle the request to `index.htm`?

Comment: Retrieve JSP page. By now, a simple "Hello world page".

Comment: No. _What_ should handle the request?

Comment: A simple GET request, using a Spring `Controller`.

Comment: And where do you have that controller configured?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I just posted the `index.htm` controller code.

Comment: You've still only shown the source code of the controller. I want to see where it is configured, why you think it should do anything. (Those are the questions you should ask yourself.)

Comment: If you're using Spring MVC anyway, why not just use Spring REST tools?

Comment: Great, so now you have a configuration, but do you have anything to load it? Well, in this case, sure, you have `ContextLoaderListener`. But what is `ContextLoaderListener`? Does it handle requests?

Comment: Ready my friend. Thanks for guide me. I will post the correct configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @sotirios-delimanolis comments, I got the correct configuration for this basic case:

**1) `web.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ms2.spectrum.security.jersery.JerseyApplication</param-value>          
        </init-param>       
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

---

**2) `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">



    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

---

**3) `applicationContext.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ms2.spectrum.**" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ms2.spectrum.security.controllers.*" />


</beans>
```

---

**4) `JerseyApplication.java`:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.ms2.spectrum.security.jersery;

import com.ms2.spectrum.security.jersey.resources.HelloWorld;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter;

/**
 *
 * @author Roger
 */
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication() {
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);
    }

}
```